# Need to select tasks based on task_type

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an HTML page with selected dynamic data. Instead it is showing data for all tasks.

I have four types of `task_type`, "work", "reminder", "work-off" and "estimate"

I only want to show data where `task_type = "work"`:

```
<tbody>

             {% for task in job.tasks %}

        <tr>
          <td>
            <!-- Dates can be formatted with Ruby date syntax -->
            {{ task.scheduled_at  | date: "%m/%d/%y %l:%M %p" }} -
            {{ task.ends_at  | date: "%m/%d/%y %l:%M %p" }}
          </td>
          <td>{{ task.name }}</td>

          <td>{{ task.task_type.name}}</td>       

          <td>{{task.task_employee.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
```

I tried an `if` statement but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
<tbody>

             {% for task in job.tasks %}
              {% if task.task_type.name = "work" then %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!-- Dates can be formatted with Ruby date syntax -->
            {{ task.scheduled_at  | date: "%m/%d/%y %l:%M %p" }} -
            {{ task.ends_at  | date: "%m/%d/%y %l:%M %p" }}
          </td>
          <td>{{ task.name }}</td>

          <td>{{ task.task_type.name}}</td>       

          <td>{{task.task_employee.name}}</td>
        </tr>
       {% end %}
      {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
```

Comment: use this as a loop statement `job.tasks.where(task_tyoe: "work").each do |task|`

Comment: Cheeky bit of liquid :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is "almost" working. 
In your `if` statement you are asking for `name = "work"` which is an  assignment, which  will always return true. Your code will work it you use the comparison operator which is `==`.

Using `=` results in bad code. Let's assume a job has 10000 Tasks. That means you are taking all of them, looping through each, and only make some HTML if the `type_name` is `work`.

It's better to  select the needed tasks, which you can do by using ActiveRecord's `where` method.

in general you can use it with

```
Class.where(attribute: value)
```

in your case it would be

```
Task.where(type_name: "work")
```

I would rather use scopes:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job

  scope :work, -> { where(type_name: "work") }
end
```

Then you can call the scopes with `Task.work` which will make

```
 SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE type_name = 'work'
```

in your template then use:

```
job.tasks.work.each do |job|
```